# connect react-redux store to express + mysql backend

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am getting used to redux with react and i have worked through a few tutorials now. I'm left confused on how I should get data from my express api (where i get data from db) to the redux store.

Say i have a file in my express backend users.js where I connect to my mysql db and return all users in my database. So in my reducers folder i have an index.js file looking something like this

```
/reducers/index.js

// would i do a fetch(/users) here to populate users array with data from db?

const initialState = {
  users: []
};

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS:
    return { ...state, users: [...state.users, action.payload] };
  }
}
```

or would the proper way be to have this return the empty array and in my component on componentDidMount(fetch(/users)...) and set state.users to my results from that fetch?

I haven't found anything solid on best practices for react/redux with express api so any answers aswell as links to clear up my confusion would be much appreciated

EDIT** If you're reading this and have similar confusion on making api calls with react/redux I have found that the best practice is to have fetch calls in action creators.

Simply import and call your action creator in your component and pass it the params you would like. For this example I put a function in my actions file called fetchUsers() where I use axios to fetch data from server.

Answer (score 0):

You should `fetch` users in your `componentDidMount()` and then in the return of promise, you can dispatch the users to your store.

```
componentDidMount(){

fetch(url).then((response)=>{
  if(response.data){
    this.props.dispatch({
    type:"SET_USERS",
    payload: response.data
    })
  }
})
```

And you should `connect()` your component to store to get the `dispatch()` in your props.